# WordPress failure

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I want to say that I am not an expert, it´s my first Wordpress project and I want to dig in. Therefore I tried to word only with Plugins and few coding.

I don´t know but since today my site has a failure and I don´t understand:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function
Cherry_Dynamic_Css_Utilities::typography_font_family(), 0 passed in /home/.sites/48/site8294423/web/wp-content/plugins/jet-elements/cherry-framework/modules/cherry-dynamic-css/cherry-dynamic-css.php on line 487 and exactly 1 expected in /home/.sites/48/site8294423/web/wp-content/plugins/jet-elements/cherry-framework/modules/cherry-dynamic-css/inc/class-cherry-dynamic-css-utilities.php:688
Stack trace: 
#0 /home/.sites/48/site8294423/web/wp-content/plugins/jet-elements/cherry-framework/modules/cherry-dynamic-css/cherry-dynamic-css.php(487): Cherry_Dynamic_Css_Utilities->typography_font_family()
#1 [internal function]: Cherry_Dynamic_Css->replace_func(Array)
#2 /home/.sites/48/site8294423/web/wp-content/plugins/jet-elements/cherry-framework/modules/cherry-dynamic-css/cherry-dynamic-css.php(327): preg_replace_callback('/@(([a-zA-Z_]+)...', Array, '/* #Typography ...')
#3 /home/.sites/48/site8294423/web/wp-content/plugins/jet-elements/cherry-framework/modu in /home/.sites/48/site8294423/web/wp-content/plugins/jet-elements/cherry-framework/modules/cherry-dynamic-css/inc/class-cherry-dynamic-css-utilities.php on line 688
```

Tried to restore backup (database and rest) but the same after backup

Can you please help a little bit....

Thank you very much

Comment: The error occurs from a plugin (Cherry-something). Deactivate the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Either via FTP, your server's file manager, or terminal, you should change the directory name of the plugin in /wp-content/plugins/jet-elements to something like /wp-content/plugins/jet-elements-DISABLED

Once done, attempt to navigate to your wordpress admin dashboard. You'll be given the option of deleting the now missing plugin "Jet Elements" (or whatever it's front name is). Delete it from there. Later, reinstall the plugin, do not activate, and delete it. This will force the plugin's native data deletion function to fire, killing all data in your database from the original install.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

problem with jet-elements plugin just go to wp-content/plugin and move or delete jet-elements folder